# spring boot cache control is not working properly. max age gets reset to 0

Tags: spring-boot, cache-control

i am trying to build my app with spring boot 1.4.3. I tried set max age as

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
      .addResourceHandler("/css/**")
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/")
      .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(30, TimeUnit.DAYS));
    }
}
```

when i access my page first time, i can see response headers with Status=200, as

```
Accept-Ranges=bytes
Cache-Control=max-age=2592000
```

Next time when i access same page second time, i can see Status=304 but headers are -

```
Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Date=Wed, 11 Jan 2017 16:05:12 GMT
Expires=0
```

Because of this when i access third time, all my static resources were fetched from server and not the cached one. Can some one help me what i am missing or doing wrong? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an issue with spring security where cache control headers are ignored in controller , please check the [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8949) to issue and the workaround at [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2953).

this issue is fixed in the latest version of spring security (5.0.2)